# use json feed to inject background-image in div

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I'm trying to use my Flickr JSON feed to inject the latest image of my feed into a specific div as a background-image.

I'm able to pull the feed, parse the image url, and log it in the console, but when i try to pop that into the css, I get an uncaught reference error.

"Uncaught ReferenceError: flickrImage is not defined"

Any ideas on how to fix this?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12" id="images">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=99895690@N00&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", displayImages);

        function displayImages(data) {

            // Now start cycling through our array of Flickr photo details
            $.each(data.items, function(i,item){

                // Change medium images to large
                var flickrImage = (item.media.m).replace("_m.jpg", "_b.jpg");
                console.log(flickrImage);

                // Break .each loop
                if (flickrImage) return false;

            });

        // Pop our CSS in the #images DIV
        $('#images').css('background-image', 'url('+ flickrImage +')');

        // Close down the JSON function call
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move `flickrImage` out of the loop for it to be defined outside of the `$.each` loop:

```
var flickrImage;

$.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
    // Change medium images to large
    flickrImage = (item.media.m).replace("_m.jpg", "_b.jpg");
    console.log(flickrImage);

    // Break .each loop
    if (flickrImage) return false;
});

$('#images').css('background-image', 'url(' + flickrImage + ')');
```

Comment: It's always the simplest thing for me haha. Thanks a bunch!